# Set class inheritance after class declaration OR setting class inheritance on const_set class

Tags: ruby, dynamic

If a class has been previously defined, how can I tell it to inherit from a class `Parent`?

For instance:

```
class Parent
  ..
end

class Klass
  ..
end
```

Now I want it to inherit from `Parent`.

I can't re-open the class and set it because I will get a class mismatch error:

```
class Klass < Parent
  ..
end
```

Specifically, I am trying to find out how to set the class inheritance on a class I am creating through `Object.const_set`.

```
klass = Object.const_set('Klass', Class.new)
```

How can I tell `Klass` to inherit from class `Parent`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no way to change the superclass of an already existing class.

To specifiy the superclass of a class you're creating dynamically, you simply pass the superclass as an argument to `Class.new`.

```
class Parent
end
klass = Class.new(Parent)
klass.superclass #=> Parent
```

Just as a side note: You're not creating the class with `const_set`. You're creating it with `Class.new`. You're simply storing the created class in a constant with `const_set`. Once `const_set` is invoked, `Class.new` has already happened and the superclass cannot be changed anymore.